# Migrating Postgres from 9.2 to 9.3

Tags: postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3, migration

I have 2 CentOS servers, one is running PostgreSQL 9.2 and the other, 9.3.

I'm trying to migrate the database but I'm getting 'relation  does not exist' errors.

What I did was on the 9.2 server:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -W -U postgres --clean DBName > dbname.dump
```

copied the dbname.dump file to the 9.3 server and then:

```
pgsql -h localhost -W -U postgres -f dbname.dump
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Other misc info, I am using the postgis extension and have some foreign key restraints.

Comment: Show the **full, exact text of the error message(s)**. I also recommend using `pg_dump -Fc` and using `pg_restore` instead of `psql`. If you use `psql` at least use `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -W -U postgres --clean -f dbname.dump DBName
```

The move the file to the new server, create the new database with

```
createdb DBName
```

then restore with:

```
psql -d DBName -f dbname.dump -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

Remember that if you have tablespaces created on the old DB you will have to manually recreate them in the new DB before importing the dump.

Comment: Managed to find out what the error was with the -v and ON_ERROR_STOP=1 flags/parameters. I didn't install postgis on the 9.3 server.